# World map (oce package) only with the 20°C SST lines

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a world map with the 20°C isothermal lines. I managed to narrow it down to two with `nlevels = 2`. Now, I don't know how to get rid of the 0°C lines. I think I need to filter the "SST" list, but I don't know how to do that.

```r
library(oce)
#> Lade nötiges Paket: gsw
library(ocedata)

data(coastlineWorld) # package: oce
data(levitus, package = "ocedata")


mapPlot(coastlineWorld, col = "lightgray", projection = "+proj=robin", drawBox = F)
mapContour(levitus[["longitude"]], levitus[["latitude"]], levitus[["SST"]], nlevels = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the last line of your code in this way: `mapContour(levitus[["longitude"]], levitus[["latitude"]],levitus[["SST"]], levels= 20)`. The option `levels` leaves a place for you to specify the contour lines you want on your plot.